# How to setup FSAA on Intel Graphics / NUC on Ubuntu?

Tags: intel-graphics, antialiasing

Anti-aliasing is running perfectly on an application running under Windows 10 on Intel Graphics UHD series embedded in a NUC.
But with the same application running under Ubuntu 22.04 and the same hardware, the anti-aliasing doesn’t seem to be available, typically `glGetIntegerv GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB` and/or `GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS` return 0 samples.

The main difference is that on Windows, there is a driver configuration [application](https://www.intel.fr/content/www/fr/fr/support/articles/000055840/graphics.html) that allows to setup anti-aliasing (enable/disable/let the app choose), but on Linux, it seems that this tool doesn’t exist.

I’ve also tried via the xorg.conf files by following these articles:
1)[Intel Graphics Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics)
2)[Configuration Details Arch Wiki](https://man.archlinux.org/man/intel.4#CONFIGURATION_DETAILS).
But I  didn’t find anything regarding anti-aliasing.

Thanks for any clues!

The chipset and drivers characteristics  are:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

*00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
DeviceName:  GPU
Subsystem: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
Kernel driver in use: i915
https://linuxconfig.org/graphics-driver-check-on-ubuntu-22-04*
```

```
$ glxinfo -B

    name of display: localhost:10.0
    display: localhost:10  screen: 0
    direct rendering: Yes
    Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
        Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
        Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
        Version: 22.0.5
        Accelerated: no
        Video memory: 3634MB
        Unified memory: no
        Preferred profile: core (0x1)
        Max core profile version: 4.5
        Max compat profile version: 4.5
        Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
        Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
    OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
    OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
    OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
    OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
    OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
    OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
    OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
    OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
    OpenGL context flags: (none)
    OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
    OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.5
    OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

```
$ vainfo

    libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
    libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
    libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
    libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
    vainfo: VA-API version: 1.14 (libva 2.12.0)
    vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.3.1 ()
```